# Django application deployment @Bluemix where postgresql is not available as a service

Tags: django, ibm-cloud, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to deploy my application into Bluemix which is using PostgreSQL as a database.

On Bluemix portal PostgreSQL is not available in listed services. How can I add it to my project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL is listed under the [Labs section](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/labs/) of the catalogue.

*This service does not come with production-grade support.*

If you want a supported version, use the service provided by [Compose](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/postgresql-by-compose/).